# Double space after MD5 Hash

Tags: md5, checksum

I have a terminal command to execute an MD5 of a hard drive.  However, this command only puts one space after the hash instead of the regular double space.  I have provided the code below

```
find * -type f -exec md5 -r {} \\; > DRIVE.md5
```

Right now, what the code is doing is:

```
12345678912345678912345678912345 Test Files/Test Files.mov
```

What I want is for it to do:

```
12345678912345678912345678912345  Test Files/Test Files.mov
```

If I use this code:

```
find * -type f -exec md5 -r {} \\; | sed 's/ /  /g' > DRIVE.md5
```

It will add the double space after the Hash, but it will also add a double space between **any** space. Example:

Original:

```
12345678912345678912345678912345 Test Files/Test Files.mov
```

Result:

```
12345678912345678912345678912345  Test  Files/Test  Files.mov
```

Anyway help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you could use sed in this way:

```
find * -type f -exec md5 -r "{}" \; | sed 's/ /  /' > DRIVE.md5
```

modifying the first space after the md5.

Comment: Okay, I'll give this a shot.  My colleague just provided me with this applescript he has.  Anyway to manipulate this?

`code`on open aDisk
 set xxx to "cd " & quoted form of (POSIX path of aDisk) & " ; find * -type f -exec md5 -r {} \\; > DRIVE.md5"
 do shell script xxx
 beep
end open`code`

Comment: modify your question to paste more code, it is not readable as a comment

Comment: Modified! I actually tried your code and it worked! I then added the sed coding to the end of the applescript where the command was typed in and all is good!  Thank you very much!! :)

Comment: after the op modify: could you please specify how it would like to modify what and how? I should point also that I'm really not into applescripts.

Comment: The script provided adds the double space, however, it adds a double space between anything that already has a space in the file name or folder name (eg. "Test Files" after the script becomes "Test  Files")  I will explain more thoroughly above

Comment: yes you are right, remove the `g` on the last part of sed to remove change only the first occurrence, I'll modify the answer.